# Idempotent homomorphisms of von Neumann algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Is there any description of unital idempotent ($F^2(x)=F(x)$) morphisms of a von Neumann algebra into itself? Or, equivalently, of weakly closed subalgebras which are retracts as von Neumann algebras?

Comment: Naive question perhaps - Why are the two questions equivalent? I don't see why the range of an unital idempotent is weakly closed. 

Comment: I had a doubt about that when asking. Indeed, these might be wo different questions. Just in my case I know that the image is weakly closed.

Comment: So can I ask a naive question: is it correct that $F$ is just an algebra homomorphism (not assumed normal, or a $*$-map, etc.?)

Comment: Matthew, mohanravi, I should have written "morphism", so normal and involutive. Then indeed the image is weakly closed since it is the kernel of $F-Id$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  The kernel of F is an ultraweakly closed *-ideal of M generated by some central projection z.
M splits as a direct sum of zM and (1-z)M.
As a 2x2 matrix F has only two nonzero entries, one that corresponds to an idempotent automorphism (hence the identity map) of (1-z)M and another one to an arbitrary morphism from (1-z)M to zM.
Thus idempotent morphisms are classified by central projections and morphisms from (1-z)M to zM.

Comment: Indeed, $G(X)=F(x)-(1-z)x$ is a morphism but one cannot get anything better...